# StackOverflowException при использовании get/set

Tags: c#

При обращении к полю для получения значения, для которого заданы `get` и `set` происходит многократное обращение к этому полю, в результате чего генерируется `StackOverflowException`. Если же сделать поле доступным, т.е. `public`, проблема исчезает.

```
class Sphere : Figure 
{ 
    public int radius 
    { 
        get { return radius; } 
        private set { radius = value; } 
    } 

    //неважный код

    public Sphere(int r, double d) : base(d) 
    { 
        this.radius = r; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста код, иллюстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Так выглядит вызов Sphere sph = (Sphere)Global.figures[number - 1];

Comment: скорее всего,вы в указываете название свойства,вместо поля. Вы можете использовать авто-свойств: `public SomeType SomeName{get;set;}`

Comment: Приведите полный пример кода. Класс с полями и обращение с вызовом.

Comment: А здесь код поля класса public int radius
        {
            get { return radius; }
            private set { radius = value; }
        }

Comment: @Надежда имя свойства должно отличаться от имени поля.

Comment: Класс с полями class Sphere:Figure
    {
        public int radius
        {
            get { return radius; }
            private set { radius = value; }
        }
        public Sphere():base()
        {
            this.radius = 1;
        }
        public Sphere(int r) : base()
        {
            this.radius = r;
        }
        public Sphere(int r, double d) : base(d)
        {
            this.radius = r;
        }
        public override double volume()
        {
            return (Math.Pow(radius, 3) * (4 / 3) * Math.PI);
        }
    }

Comment: так делать нельзя,используйте авто-свойства: `public int radius { get; private set;} `

Comment: @Надежда Не добавляйте код в комментариях. Вместо этого используйте ссылку [edit] чтобы изменить вопрос.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Твой код:

```
int radius 
{ 
    get { return radius; } 
    private set { radius = value; } 
}
```

при присвоении ты вызываешь замкнутый цыкл, с которого невозможно выйти.(включи дебаг и понажимай F11 что бы увидеть что именно комп делает)

Как исправить?

Вариант 1:

```
private int _radius;
public int Radius 
{ 
    get { return _radius; } 
    private set { _radius = value; } 
}
```

Вариант 2:

```
public int Radius { get; private set;}
```