# Переполнение Стэка в простенькой программе

Tags: c#, stackoverflow

пишу тренировочную программу и возникла проблема с переполнением стэка.

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using Persons;

namespace firstMainProjecct
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int Clients = 1;
            int ClientsNum = 0;
            int Employees = 1;
            int EmployeesNum = 0;
            Client[] clientsAr = new Client[Clients];
            Employee[] EmployeesAR = new Employee[Employees];
            while (true)
            {
                WriteLine("1)Client menu");
                WriteLine("2)Employee menu");
                WriteLine("3)setting menu");
                WriteLine("4)Exit");
                switch (int.Parse(ReadLine()))
                {
                    case 1:
                        WriteLine("1)Add Clien");
                        WriteLine("2)Display All Client");
                        switch (int.Parse(ReadLine()))
                        {
                            case 1:
                                clientsAr[ClientsNum] = new Client(ReadLine(), ReadLine());
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                for (int i = 0; i < clientsAr.Length; i++)
                                {
                                    WriteLine(clientsAr[i]);
                                }
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        WriteLine("1)Add Employee");
                        WriteLine("2)Display All Employee");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        WriteLine("1)Edit Minimum Sum");
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                Clear();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

И так же библиотека классов -

```
using System;

namespace Persons
{
    public abstract class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public Person(string name, string lastname)
        {
            Name = name;
            LastName = lastname;

        }
        public virtual void Display()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Name:{Name} LastName: {LastName}");
        }
    }
    public class Client : Person
    {
        public int Sum
        {
            get
            {
                return Sum;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value > minSum)
                    Sum = value;
                else
                    throw new Exception($"Balance can't be less than {minSum}");
            }
        }
        public readonly int minSum = 0;
        public Client(string name, string lastName)
            : base(name,lastName)
        {
            Sum = 1;
        }
        public override void Display()
        {
            base.Display();
            Console.WriteLine($"On a bank account: {Sum}$");
        }
    }
    public class Employee : Person
    {
        public string post
        {
            get
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(post))
                    return post;
                else
                    return "Not found";
            }
            set
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                    post = value;
                else
                    throw new Exception("The field cannot be empty.");
            }
        }
        public Employee(string name, string lastName)
            : base(name, lastName)
        {

        }
        public override void Display()
        {
            base.Display();
            Console.WriteLine($"Consists of positions: {post}");
        }
    }
}
```

Так же вот сообщение с консоли

```
Stack overflow.
Repeat 16062 times:
--------------------------------
   at Persons.Client.set_Sum(Int32)
--------------------------------
   at Persons.Client..ctor(System.String, System.String)
   at firstMainProjecct.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

т.к я ещё начинаю, код достаточно некрасивый и неправильный, но если вам не ссложно, помогите решить проблему с моей ошибкой

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/644314/220553

Comment: У вас в методе `set` поля `summ` бесконечная рекурсия
Посмотрите примеры использования свойств в доке: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties

Comment: @SergeySkvortsov там и в геттере, и в сеттере рекурсия

Comment: @return Да, вы правы